# How do I correctly sourcemap in a multi-package monorepo built with yarn workspaces?

Tags: javascript, typescript, yarn-workspaces

I have a yarn workspace with two packages

- PackageA
- PackageB

PackageB depends on PackageA, so there is a symlink in the root node_modules to PackageA. When I build and run PackageB, it correctly follows `PackageA/package.json#browser -> PackageA/dist/umd/index.js` and executes that code.

What I would like is to sourcemap `PackageA/dist/umd/index.js` to the TypeScript source (PackageA/src) from which it is built.

Comment: Do you have `"declarationMap": true` in your tsconfig `compilerOptions`?

Comment: Just tried that. Didn't help

Comment: Hmm, the only other thing I can think of is `"declaration": true`, but I assume you already have that. Both would need to be in the tsconfig for your `PackageA`.

Comment: I tried adding devtool: 'source-map' to my webpack config, so that the bundle js would generate a sourcemap. Then I used source-map-loader in the consuming project to load that. It wasn't very helpful, because every time I step into the package bundle it just shows me the UMD wrapper.